# Storing Arabic Words using Apache Solr 3.6.1

Tags: php, solr, arabic

For Arabic to search & index  have configured the following ,

Schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

OUTPUT in Browser:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="company_name">?????</str>
<str name="id">1</str>
<arr name="search_supplier_keyword">
<str>?????</str>
</arr>
<str name="supplier_name">?????</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

But the words in Arabic are not stored instead it stored as Question Mark(??????).

Is there anything i have missed, help me in.

Thanks In Advance